# Is it possible to create your own AWS static S3 login HTML page for IAM credential login?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I would like to create my own HTML page to allow users to login using the IAM credentials. I could not find any reference how to do it without getting the credential token first. I would like to host this on an AWS S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of Javascript web app and using Javascript SDK for AWS cognito could work to serve your purposes.

Example of creating a page using Javascript to log in users with Facebook login and access an S3 bucket.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-started-browser.html
https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/browser/

Using Cognito

> Amazon Cognito lets you easily add user sign-up and sign-in to your mobile and web apps. With Amazon Cognito, you also have the options to authenticate users through social identity providers such as Facebook, Twitter, or Amazon, with SAML identity solutions, or by using your own identity system. In addition, Amazon Cognito enables you to save data locally on users devices, allowing your applications to work even when the devices are offline. You can then synchronize data across users devices so that their app experience remains consistent regardless of the device they use.

https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/

Answer (score 0):

[AWS S3 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) clearly explains, it's not possible.

> You can host a static website on Amazon S3. On a static website,
>   individual web pages include static content. They may also contain
>   client-side scripts. By contrast, a dynamic website relies on
>   server-side processing, including server-side scripts such as PHP,
>   JSP, or ASP.NET. Amazon S3 does not support server-side scripting.

If you mean, you would like to grant access to HTML content for only certain users without their IAM, you could explore [S3 pre-signed object URL option](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html).

Comment: I do not see an explanation on the AWS S3 site, but I did find articles on federated access to S3 via other auth providers like Google. I would think that AWS IAM users should also be able to authenticate. i could be wrong though....

Answer (score 0):

IAM username/password credentials are **only** for use with the AWS console.

There is no exposed API that you can use to validate IAM credentials.

> Q: Is there an authentication API to verify IAM user sign-ins?
>
> No. There is no programmatic way to verify user sign-ins.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/iam/faqs/

Comment: "only for use with the AWS console" I don;t think this statement is 100% correct, they can used with CLI and SDK too.